# Error with PHP Form, Keeps Redirecting to login page

Tags: php, mysql, forms, authentication

Ok so here is my issue. I have created a simple login system for a few pages. That all works. I just created another page with a php form that submits input to mysql database. That all works as well...on other pages on my site. 

For some reason, when I submit this form, it keeps redirecting to my login page and I have no idea why. Here is the form/code that I am trying to submit:

```
<form method="post" action="admin_home.php?page=search.php">
<p>Search by date range: </p>
From: <input type="text" id="from" name="from" />To: <input type="text" id="to" name="to" />
<BR>
<p>Search by:</p>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
Phone Number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" />
<input name="export" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

That form is in the file search.php where the search results are also displayed below the form.
Here is the login code I have on the admin_home.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("admin_logincheck.php");
if (!(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] != '')) {

header ("Location: admin_index.php");

}
?>
```

....then displaying whatever.

And here is my admin_logincheck.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();
session_name("MemberLogin");


$hostname = "";
$username = "";
$dbname = "";
$password = "";

if($_GET['action'] == "login") {

mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
mysql_select_db($dbname);


$name = $_POST['user'];
$q_user = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$name'");

if(mysql_num_rows($q_user) == 1) {

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$name'");
$data = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if($_POST['pass'] == $data['password']) {
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
header("Location: admin_home.php"); // This is the page that you want to open if the user successfully logs in to your website.
exit;
}
            else {
                header("Location: admin_index.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Wrong Password'));
                exit;
            }

} 
else {
    header("Location: admin_index.php?login=failed&cause=".urlencode('Invalid User'));
exit;
}
}

// if the session is not registered
//if(session_is_registered("name") == false) {
if ($_SESSION['name'] == false) {   
header("Location: admin_index.php");
}
?>
All
```

my other pages are fine, but for some reason that one form/search page keeps redirecting to my login page. Any help is greatly appreciated. I hope it made sense lol.

Comment: What is in your admin_logincheck? Seems like the login doesn't work

Comment: I'll edit my post and add it. The admin_logincheck works, it's just as soon as I added this page.

Comment: So you're script is redirecting you to admin_index.php?login=failed&cause=WrongPassword?

Comment: It just plain redirects to admin_index.php. No failed code is given. That's why it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: where do you want to go? check BOSS's answer, it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
if (!(isset($_SESSION['name']) && $_SESSION['name'] != '')) {
header ("Location: admin_index.php");
}
```

with this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['name']) && !empty($_SESSION['name'])) {
header ("Location: admin_index.php");
}
```

Comment: Note that if (!empty($some_var)) ... is enough. You do not need to use isset($some_var) first because empty() does that already (and it considers an unset variables as empty).

Comment: Hey Boss, that didn't work. It doesn't let me login, just takes me to admin_index.php